# Unable to install MongoDB 7.0 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I'm following the official guide to [install MongoDB Community Edition on Ubuntu](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).

After executing the commands step by step:

> **(1) Import the public key used by the package management system.**
>
> From a terminal, install gnupg and curl if they are not already available:
>
> `sudo apt-get install gnupg curl`
>
> To import the MongoDB public GPG key from https://pgp.mongodb.com/server-7.0.asc, run the following command:
>
> ```
> curl -fsSL https://pgp.mongodb.com/server-7.0.asc | \
>     sudo gpg -o /usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-7.0.gpg \
>     --dearmor
> ```
>
> **(2) Create a list file for MongoDB**
>
> Create the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-7.0.list file for Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy):
>
> ```
> echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-7.0.gpg ] https://repo.mongodb.com/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/7.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-7.0.list
> ```
>
> **(3) Reload local package database**
>
> Issue the following command to reload the local package database:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> ```

I'm getting the following error:

```
E: The repository 'https://repo.mongodb.com/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/7.0 Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list file URL https://repo.mongodb.com/apt/ubuntu is invalid. It contains only the `mongodb-enterprise` packages. You need to use https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu to get the `mongodb-org` community edition package.

Here is the corrected command for step **(2) Create a list file for MongoDB**:

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-7.0.gpg ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/7.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-7.0.list
```